# Installing ATI driver on Thinkpad T60 (WinXP)

Tags: windows-xp, thinkpad

I have received an old IBM Thinkpad T60, Type 6372-63G.

I've installed Windows XP SP3 on it, but I am having trouble getting any drivers installed for the ATI graphics card. I have tried several driver versions from Lenovo's website.  But, it seems like it will simply not install the driver.

What is causing this and how can I get a video driver installed that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you get the ATI drivers from the Official [AMD drivers site](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) as they will be up to date. You can search your model there and it will link you to the correct download. However, looking at the [T60 drivers site](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/MIGR-62928.html), it seems to only be Intel Graphics Drivers, so make sure that you actually do have an ATI card before installing drivers.

On further research, it appears that laptop model uses Intel Graphics, so take a look at the the [T60 driver page](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/MIGR-62928.html) again.

Comment: Simon you were right - it doesn't have a ATI card. Sorry about that - my google-fu muist have failed me...

Comment: Haha, it happens. Just grab those intel ones :)